# How to stop pictures showing in the end of python? (i show my code)

Tags: python

I use batch plotting to save pictures which I have used plot function to draw in python. But when it run to final , pictures which i had saved start to show in command windows one by one. I didn't use show function. I want to reduce the run time. how can i do ?
sorry ,my old question is closed  so i publish another

```
for k in range(3):
    k1 = ["s","m","h"]
    plt.figure(figsize=(10.21,25))
    plt.plot([0,4],[0,0],color='lightcoral')#
    plt.plot([0,4],[10,10],color='lightcoral')#     
    plt.plot([0,0],[0,10],color='lightcoral')#     
    plt.plot([4,4],[0,10],color='lightcoral')# 
    #------------------------------------    
    #plt.yaxis.set_ticks([0,10000])
    #plt.xaxis.set_ticks([0,4000])
    length_a8 = len(a)
    for i in range(1,length_a8):
        A = []
        B = []
        C = []
        D = []  
        length_a9 = len(a[i])           
        for j in range(length_a9):
            tempA = eval(a[i][j][0])/1000
            A.append(tempA)
            tempB = eval(a[i][j][1])/1000
            B.append(tempB)
            tempC = eval(a[i][j][2])
            C.append(tempC)
            tempD = eval(a[i][j][3])
            D.append(tempD)
        length_a10 = len(A)-1    
        for i in range(length_a10):

            if C[i] <= 6 and k == 0 and D[i] > 0:  
                plt.plot([A[i],A[i+1]],[B[i],B[i+1]],color='orange')
            elif C[i] > 6 and C[i] <= 19 and k == 1 and D[i] > 0: 
                plt.plot([A[i],A[i+1]],[B[i],B[i+1]],color='cornflowerblue')
            elif C[i] > 19 and k == 2 and D[i] > 0:
                plt.plot([A[i],A[i+1]],[B[i],B[i+1]],color='red')
    #plt.plot([0,1],[0,2])
    plt.plot([0,0],[0,0])
    plt.savefig("test_new_"+k1[k])
```

Comment: As an aside, why are you using `eval()` here?

Comment: because the value in a[] is string ,so i change it to int

Comment: If you want to convert a string to an int, just use `int()`.